# Adding a column Status to manage add or removing of a row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, addition, rows

I've always used a column `Status` with datatype `bit` to signify that a row is in use or not. But is it a good practice to keep it every single table of the database whether it be a master records table or a transaction table.

Comment: `Status` to me implies one of many possible values - therefore, a `BIT` seems like a bad choice for the datatype (I would use `INT` or `SMALLINT`). If you want to signal active or not, use something like `IsActive BIT` - that clearly conveys that you have a yes/no answer here - and nothing else....

Comment: That was a good suggestion. However, should it be done for all the tables in the database or just the master records?

Comment: Depends: is there any possibility that the "child" tables will have a different `IsActive` state than the master record? If so: then you need the `IsActive` on each table. If that case is 150% impossible - then you don't need the `IsActive` on each table - once on the master is sufficient